# Run multiple process server before client

Tags: c, linux, struct, posix

I am still working on the same homework of Operating System course. Now , here is my question (Firstly, I am rewriting the HW's content):
Two programs will be implemented : a client program "get" and a server program called "iserv". A client will ask the server to retrieve and sent all integers in a certain range. The server will be a multi-process program. It will create child processes to handle requests coming from clients. POSIX message queues will be used.
Here my iserv.c (server program)

```
struct item   /*struct for client requests to the server*/
{
    int maxvalue;
    int minvalue;
    char *queuename;
};

int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{
    pid_t apid1;
    FILE *fp;
    mqd_t mq;
    const char *msgqueue = "/serverqueue";
    int oflag = (O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
    mode_t mode = (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);


    if(argc != 3)
    {
        printf("wrong number of arguments");
        exit(1);
    }
    //create server message queue
    mq = mq_open(msgqueue ,oflag , mode , NULL);
    if(mq==-1)
    {
        perror("can not open msg queue\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("mq opened , mq id = %d\n" , (int) mq);



    //******get the maxvalue and minvalue*******



    mq_getattr(mq , &attr);
    printf("mq maximum msgsize = %d\n" , (int) attr.mq_msgsize);
    /*allocate large enough space for the buffer*/
    buflen = attr.mq_msgsize;
    bufptr = (char *)malloc(buflen);
    n = mq_receive(mq , (char *)bufptr , buflen , NULL);

    if(n == -1)
    {
        perror("mq_receive failed\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    itemptr = (struct item *) bufptr;

    printf("min value = %d\n" , itemptr->minvalue);
    printf("max value = %d\n" , itemptr->maxvalue);
    fprintf(stderr , "queue name = %s\n" , itemptr->queuename);


    free(bufptr);
    mq_close(mq);
    mq_unlink(msgqueue);
    return 0;
}
```

and get.c(client program)

```
struct item   /*struct for client requests to the server*/
{
    int maxvalue;
    int minvalue;
    char *queuename;
};



int main(int argc , char *argv[])
{

    FILE *file;
    mqd_t mq;
    mqd_t mq2;

    const char *msgqueue = "/serverqueue";
    int oflag = (O_RDWR|O_CREAT);
    mode_t mode = (S_IRUSR|S_IWUSR);
    struct mq_attr *attr = NULL;

    struct item item; //for serverqueue

    int n;

        if(argc != 5)
    {
        printf("wrong number of arguments");
        exit(1);

    mq = mq_open(msgqueue ,oflag , mode , attr);

    if(mq==-1)
    {
        perror("can not open msg queue\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    printf("mq opened , mq id = %d\n" , (int) mq);


    //send max - min values and the client message queue name to the serverqueue as a request
    while(1)
    {
        item.maxvalue = atoi(argv[3]);
        item.minvalue = atoi(argv[2]);
        item.queuename = clientqueue;

        n = mq_send(mq , (char *) &item , sizeof(item) , 0);
        if(n==-1)
        {
            perror("mq_send failed\n");
            exit(1);
        }
        else
        {
            printf("mq_send success , item size = %d\n" , sizeof(struct item));
            printf("%d" , item.maxvalue);
            printf("%d" , item.minvalue);
            printf("\n" , item.queuename);
        }

    }


    mq_close(mq);
    mq_unlink(msgqueue);
    return 0;

}
```

Makefile:

```
all: iserv get
iserv: iserv.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o iserv iserv.c -lrt
get: get.c
    gcc -g -Wall -o get get.c -lrt

clean:
    rm -fr *o iserv get
```

Now , my first question is even if I remove the message queue by using mq_close and mq_unlink , when I want to run these two programs terminal says that : nothing do be done for 'all'. I need to remove something else to rerun these two programs without closing or deleting anything with hand. What is this??

Second question is that `char *queuename;` in the message response cannot be taken by the server as a name. It prints out something silly on the terminal , how can I pass the string queuename to the server in this message response??

Please help me , homework due date is close I need to solve these problems , thank you for all help !!

Comment: \`backticks\` are for inline `code`. Indent four spaces for code blocks (that's what the **{ }** code button does).

Comment: Thank you for fixing me . Now I need an answer to my questions:)

Comment: "nothing to do for all" sounds like `make` telling you nothing changed so there is nothing to rebuild.  What's your second question?

Comment: Your code doesn't show the variable `clientqueue` but I am guessing that it is just a pointer and you are writing that pointer, rather than the string it points to, into the mq.  You need to `strcpy` (or similar) the string into your message buffer.

Comment: Yes , I did not write the variable, it is defined as "const char *clientqueue = "/clientqueue"; "

Comment: For referring to my first question , while testing the assistant will try to run the same code without closing terminal with giving different names to the message queue , so you say that there is nothing to be done in my code for allowing this situation?

Comment: Thus , is it enough to use mq_close and mq_link?

Comment: Right so `item.queuename = clientqueue;` isn't what you want.  (1) item.queuename needs to be a char array and (2) you need to `strncpy` the value rather than just assign the pointer.

Comment: Offhand I don't see anything wrong with your `mq_close` or `mq_unlink`.  I think you ran `make` again when you just meant to run the programs and got confused by the error because you never changed the source between runs and therefore there was nothing to build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is your main problem:

```
struct item   /*struct for client requests to the server*/
{
    int maxvalue;
    int minvalue;
    char *queuename;  //<=== NO GOOD
};
```

You can't send a pointer to another process through the MQ - what it points to in the sending process is meaningless in the receiving process.  You need to change that pointer into a fixed length character array.  Something like

```
char queuename[50];
```

As I said in the comment, you need to copy the queuename into that array.

Comment: Now I have one more problem. I need to write these result integers ( in the wanted range ) by reading them from this clientqueue. I am able to read but when I use fprintf(outfile , "%1d" , numberptr->validnumber);

Comment: It does not write anything on the output file. What can be the reason? The output file is opened like it: FILE *outfile = fopen(argv[4] , "w");

Comment: Okey I have the answer:)